# MySQL -> PostgreSQL SQL statement with GROUP by conflict

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

In MySQL is SQL statement:

```
SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM ossn_entities as e 
JOIN ossn_entities_metadata as emd ON e.guid=emd.guid 
WHERE(e.subtype='gender' AND e.type='user' AND emd.value = 'male') 
ORDER by e.guid ASC ;
```

which gives me correct answer 5.

I modified this statement to PostgreSQL to :

```
SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM ossn_entities as e 
JOIN ossn_entities_metadata as emd ON e.guid=emd.guid 
WHERE(e.subtype='gender' AND e.type='user' AND emd.value = 'male') 
GROUP BY e.guid 
ORDER by e.guid ASC ;
```

and now is the answer:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

which is incorrect.

I modify this MySQL because of PostgreSQL error:

```
ERROR:  column "e.guid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How to modify MySQL statement to get correct answer 5 not the array?

Comment: MySql allows `ORDER by e.guid ASC` what makes little sense in this context. Just remove `ORDER BY...` from MySql query.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You only read the first half of the error message:

> ERROR:  column "e.guid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause...

when it's actually the second half that is what you want in this case:

> ...or be used in an aggregate function

Sorting by individual items doesn't make any sense when what you're outputting is an aggregate (sum, count, etc) of whole groups of those items. Which value of `e.guid` would it sort by if there are 50 different values in the group?

MySQL has the questionable feature of just guessing; pretty much other DBMS makes you clarify. For instance, you might sort by the lowest (`ORDER BY MIN(e.guid)`) or the average (`ORDER BY AVG(e.guid)`). This is what is meant by "must ... be used in an aggregate function".

However, in your example, you are returning *exactly one row*, so the `ORDER BY` doesn't make any sense anyway - how do you sort one thing? So if the example you give is actually the real query, the answer is to remove the `ORDER BY e.guid` completely, because it was never doing anything in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is incorrect. MySQL let's it slip through, but it's still incorrect. You aggregate (`count(*)`) without any `GROUP BY`, so you get one result row. This one row gets "sorted" by `guid`. As you don't specify which `guid` you want picked for the row (e.g. the maximum or minimum found), you get one arbitrarily picked. However, one row sorted is just that one row; there simply is nothing to sort. So the query is actually:

```
SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM ossn_entities as e 
JOIN ossn_entities_metadata as emd ON e.guid = emd.guid 
WHERE e.subtype = 'gender' AND e.type = 'user' AND emd.value = 'male';
```

which is valid in both MySQL and PostgreSQL and about any other RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try simply dropping

```
 GROUP BY e.guid ORDER by e.guid ASC
```

since you want a single value, you cannot be grouping by guid, much less ordering by it. MySQL probably tries to ignore this inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks. This solution helps.